# Schengen visa for Spain for my parents

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, applications

I've been living in Spain for 4 years. This year I'm inviting my parents to Spain for 90 days so they need a Schengen visa. Last year they visited as tourists (without Carta). This time, I've obtained a *Carta Invitacion* from the Spanish National Police with the exact needed dates. Their start date is August 2, 2018.

My current NIE Expires on 1 July 2018. My company processes my renewal, which would only be in June. However, it takes about 2+ months to receive my renewed NIE. I've heard from past applicants that the Spanish consulate in Mumbai did not issue their spouse the Schengen visa if the NIE of the inviting person was expiring (or the end date must be before the NIE's end date).

How do I proceed with my parents' application? Is it sufficient to send my work contract, which is valid until March 2019 to support my parents' application? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Minor nitpick: technically it would be your residence permit which expires, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, its Residence + Work Permit card which is issued for 1 year and for renewal we need to submit work contract. My work contract is still Mar 2019 (which is also renewed 1 month before expiry date)!

Comment: VTC: what exactly is being asked, as Carta was issued? I don't see an answerable question on this one. OP has not returned to TSE.